# JDBC insert statement is not working

Tags: java, jdbc, insert

I am trying to insert new record, using jdbc. Everything look like ok, I don't have any exception, but new record isn't inserted into the table. Select statement works right.

```
  public Connection getConnection(){
    Connection conn=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    return conn;
}

public void insertDish(String name, float mass, float price, String description,int pizzeria_id) {
        String insertStr = "insert into \"Dish\"(name,mass,price,description,pizzeria_id) values("+"'"+name+"'"+", "+mass+", "+price+", "+"'"+description+"'"+", "+pizzeria_id+")";

      Connection conn = getConnection();

    try {
        Statement sql = conn.createStatement();
        sql.executeUpdate(insertStr);
        sql.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: what happens if you take your sql and try to run it directly in the db?

Comment: are you sure no exception is there ?

Comment: Sql statement adds new record directly in db. It's ok. It isn't workink with jdbc.

Comment: I am absolutly sure: there isn't any exceptions.

Comment: String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/PizzaDeliver?user=postgres&password=somepassword";

Comment: PreparedStatement!  PreparedStatement!  PreparedStatement!

Comment: Have you ever used that driver before? has it worked before for insert instructions? Also, do you get any errors when it fails to insert?

Comment: PreparedStatement gives the same result

Comment: It is GWT project. I use GWT RPC for communication with a server. I just call method insertDish() and there is not anything important in the rest of code.

Comment: Wow -- `String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/PizzaDeliver?user=postgres&password=somepassword";` and `values("+"'"+name+"'"+", "+mass+", "+price+" ...` -- you are just **asking** to be hacked.

Comment: I am just trying now to resolv problem with jdbc, not to think about security.

Comment: What is the return value from `sql.executeUpdate(insertStr);` ?

Answer (score 10):

I have had a similar situation where my DB query software didn't see inserts/updates done from my Java program because they weren't committed, and therefore were not visible to other connections.

Try doing an explicit commit right after executing the statement:

```
sql.executeUpdate(insertStr);
conn.commit(); // ADDED
sql.close();
```

If that works you may want to adjust your AutoCommit settings, or just stay with the explicit commit.

Comment: It didn't help. Maybe there is some problems with postgresql 9, I will try tu use older version.

Answer (score 1):

I would try disabling Auto Commit and doing the transaction manually, see if that helps.